# React: Sanatizer / Replace User Input (directly)

Tags: reactjs, date, input, sanitize

Wassup Guys,

I am currently writing a React component (dateFormatter) for users, so they can quickly enter datetimes with (digits) numbers instead of using a calendar.

So, for example, if someone writes a date with or without literals, it should be corrected directly to a correct format ((dd/mm/yyyy) & (mm/dd/yyyy) for us / german layout). To make it a little bit more easy to disinguish between ***0***'s, I use a ***--*** syntax.

```
 expect(dateFormatter("12/16/5---0")).toBe("12/16/5---");
```

I already wrote a **test** for this, how it should work and what numbers are allowed technically
[here is my code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-khorana-mkz22?file=/src/App.test.js:4788-4847).

Currently I get the user's live input through React's onChange like this:

```
  const inputValue = date.target.value;
```

At the end I just want to use **dateFormatter**(*inputValue*) to sanitize everything and send it back. 
How can I achieve this? 
My current Idea was with if cases + regex replacement, but I have no idea actually.

Thanks in advance.

> 02112009 => 02/11/2009

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the direct approach? Something like:

```js
function Input() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <input
      onChange={e => setValue(dateFormatter(e.target.value))}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: That is my idea lmao. I'm just wondering, what the most effective way would be, in order to gurantee the formatted date, not how to call the method.